# http > https wrong final url (subdomain redirect)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I have:

directory tree:

```
└───domains
    ├───bar.com
    │   ├───sub (sub.bar.com / www.sub.bar.com)
    │   ├───sub2 (sub2.bar.com / www.sub2.bar.com)
    │   └───www (bar.com / www.bar.com)
    └───foo.com
        ├───sub (sub.foo.com / www.sub.foo.com)
        ├───sub2 (sub2.foo.com / www.sub2.foo.com)
        └───www (foo.com / www.foo.com)
```

```
/.htaccess


RewriteEngine On

# remove www from URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,DPI,L,NC]

# subdomains (sub.foo.com, sub.bar.com, sub2.foo.com, sub2.bar.com)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*\.[^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2/%1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) /domains/%2/%1/$1 [DPI]

# main domains (foo.com, bar.com)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]*\.[^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%1 -d
RewriteRule (.*) /domains/%1/www/$1 [DPI]
```

This looks that works quite well, but when I need to enable https on `foo.com`, that doesn't work as expected.

```
/domains/foo.com/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [DPI,R=301]
```

Because instead of redirect: http://www.sub.foo.com/?query > https://sub.foo.com/?query it redirect to: https://sub.foo.com/domains/foo.com/sub/?query but it really is not what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `/domains/foo.com/.htaccess`
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [DPI,R=301]
> ```

This doesn't work as expected when used in the `/domains/foo.com/.htaccess` file because it is being processed *after* the URL has been rewritten by the `/.htaccess` file in the root directory and by this stage the `REQUEST_URI` server variable has been updated to the full URL-path that the request has been rewritten to (not the URL that the user requested), ie. `/domains/foo.com/sub/`.

(*Aside:* You've not stated if you are using PHP, but to clarify just in case... the `REQUEST_URI` PHP superglobal variable, ie. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`), is not the same as the `REQUEST_URI` Apache server variable. The `REQUEST_URI` PHP variable contains the URL that the user requested (which appears to be what you are expecting of the Apache server variable), which in this case is not the same as the Apache server variable of the same name.)

The simple solution is to capture the URL-path from the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, instead of using the `REQUEST_URI` Apache server variable.

For example:

```
# /domains/foo.com/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In `.htaccess`, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path less the directory-prefix - so it is always relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

The `DPI` flag would not seem to be required here.

The alternative solution is to move your HTTP to HTTPS redirect to the root `/.htaccess` file (*before* the internal rewrites) and maybe check for the requested *hostname* if you need to be selective. For example:

```
# /.htaccess
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.foo\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

In the root `/.htaccess` file we can use the Apache variable `REQUEST_URI` providing the redirect is placed *before* the internal rewrites.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. Preferably test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

---

> ```
> # remove www from URL
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,DPI,L,NC]
> ```

Another "problem" is that your www to non-www redirect always redirects to HTTP. So, a request for `https://www.sub.foo.com/` will be redirected back to HTTP before (hopefully) being redirected back to HTTPS - an unnecessary additional redirect. There are a number of ways you can resolve this depending on your requirements.